# Combine backbone collection / javascript objects with new models from the server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a collection of locations on a google map object, stored in a Backbone collection:

```
var Location = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        latitute: "",
        longitude: "",
        visited: false;
    },
});

var LocationCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Location,
    url: 'api/locations'
});
```

As each point is clicked on the map, the location model property 'visited' is set to true.

The original collection of locations comes from the database (based on the bounds of the map), which does not store any 'visited' information, simply a list of locations within range.

When the user changes the bounds of the Google map, by moving around, zooming in/out etc, I need to retrieve a brand new list of locations within the new parameters, then somehow assimilate this list with the existing collection, adding new locations, but retaining the visited properties for existing ones?

I hope this isn't too vague, but where to start?? Is there a way with jQuery to map complex objects from one collection to another? Or would it make more sense to split the collections, sending visited information back to the server and combine them there? Or will the Backbone collection remember 'visited' values and only update those in the collection with new properties?

Sorry, I thought I knew this stuff, but I have never ever done anything like this.

Comment: "I thought I knew this stuff." That's me every day. ;-) It sounds like all you need is one collection for your locations and to simply add the new location model data to it without messing with the old. Underscore provides a lot of great tools to map complex objects, collections, etc. but in your case I don't think you need to do any of that and you don't need to have your server do anything unnecessarily complex. I provide my specific take in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. Basically, I'm assuming the following. The user has a bunch of locations. They click and the location attribute changes to `visited = true;`

When they zoom out, you `fetch()` new models that are now in view but you also want don't want those old locations to reset to `visited = false;` Server will basically calculate the dimensions of the view and provide a bunch of location models.

If this is what you want, all you need to do is make a `fetch()` call with the options: `add:true`.

```
collection.fetch({
    add: true
});
```

When you pass the `add:true` option to your `fetch()` call, it won't reset the collection (thereby wiping your visited data). Instead, it will only add models that don't already exist in the collection. So if you already have locations.id = 1, 2, 3 and your server returns locations.id = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ... only 4, 5, 6 will be added to your already existing collection. The visited = true (or false) data of 1, 2, 3 should remain intact.

Comment: Brilliant! It was either going to be really easy or really hard! Thanks.

Comment: +1, note: I think in Backbone 1.0 you will also need merge: false